# Create an Identity column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, identity

I am trying to create a column with incrementing numbers inside a group as per Table below.

| RecordID | OrderID | IncrementInGroup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 |
| b | 2 | 1 |
| c | 3 | 1 |
| a | 4 | 2 |
| a | 5 | 3 |
| a | 6 | 4 |
| a | 7 | 5 |
| b | 8 | 2 |
| c | 9 | 2 |

I am having dozens of millions of rows. I guess VIEW would be enough as I want this to pick up with Power BI app. Is it possible to do for an existing table?

Comment: Is SQL Server 2005 even supported by (current versions of) PowerBI?  SQL Server 2005's support ended *completely* over *6 years* ago; it it *long* past time you sorted out your upgrade path.

Comment: Looks like you just want a `ROW_NUMBER` though; I'm pretty sure that was supported in SQL Server 2005, but I haven't touched that version of SQL Server since 2009!

Comment: Also, `INDEX` has a specific meaning in database engines, what you want here isn't an index, nor are you *indexing*. It isn't a `SEQUENCE` either, which is a tool added in  SQL Server 2012, that has similar functionality to an `IDENTITY`. Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)